# We push and pull like a magnet "do" (or "does")?

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

Ed Sheeran sings in his *Shape of You*:

> ...we push and pull like a magnet **do**

Shouldn't that **do** be a **does**, since magnet is a singular noun?

Comment: Neither are needed, however **does** is correct.

Comment: Yep, it might sound good without the verb. But in the song he uses it, and he uses the **do** form. Is this kind of like acceptable "mistake"?

Comment: [Artistic license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license).

Comment: Even under artistic license I'd rather parse this as unusual word order (i.e., a permutation of "We do push and pull like a magnet") than a congruence-mishap

Comment: A pop song's not the best place to find grammar so ELL is where I go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: the verb "do" is associated with the magnet, not with us. But he's rhyming here:

> I'm in love with the shape of you /
>   We push and pull like a magnet do /
>   Although my heart is falling too...

Sadly, grammar is sacrificed for His Art. :-)

Comment: Unleashing the power of Art vs. grammar : )

Comment: It's not really a sacrifice; we call it artistic license :)

Comment: It's something musicians do all the time, to fit a rhyme or just because the grammatically correct word doesn't fit the melody. I remember this line from The Beatles:

"She's got a ticket to ride, she's got a ticket to ride, she's got a ticket to ride, but she don't care"

I guess "doesn't" didn't fit the music or the rhythm

Comment: The art of words is to write it without breaking grammar and the art of singing is to say it without stammer.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I see what you did there

Comment: Poets do it too: "Let us go then, you and I, / When the evening is spread out against the sky ... ."

Comment: @DavidK song writers are basically poets, at least in the rhyming part

Comment: @JorgeUrreta Eh, *she don’t* is a pretty common construction in a variety of vernaculars. Clearly, *don’t* fits and *doesn’t*, well, doesn’t, but I think *she don’t* would have been preferable to the Beatles even if that weren’t the case; it sounds more natural/comfortable/informal that way, where *she doesn’t* sounds a bit stiff and formal. (But then, maybe I’m just being influenced by the awesome impact the Beatles had on culture.) Anyway, *a magnet do* sounds considerably more awkward to my ear (but then I haven’t heard Ed Sheeran sing it, his voice is better than the one in my head).

Comment: @StephenS True, and poets also are concerned with rhythm, so I guess my comment was redundant. :-)

Comment: @KRyan anything sounds better than the alternative when the alternative breaks a rhyme scheme